# Stack Overflow Worldwide Meetups 2012

Tags: discussion

We're having a Stack Overflow meetup to get together with fellow programming, web, and other technology enthusiasts. But not all of our programmers and technology enthusiasts live on Stack Overflow, so this year we're explicitly expanding the Meetup Everywhere to include the whole Stack Exchange tech family. As a Programmers participant, you're invited, too!

We [recently announced](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/stack-overflow-meetup-everywhere-april-28-2012/) the Second Annual Stack Overflow Meetup Everywhere day. This year, it will be on Saturday, April 28 (though local groups are welcome to pick any other day that week if a Saturday doesn't work for most of your members).

**What:** Stack Overflow worldwide meetups

**When:** Saturday, April 28, 2012

**Where:** your city!

**Who:** All users on Stack Exchange technology sites

You can visit the [official Meetup.com page](http://www.meetup.com/stackoverflow/) to find existing groups near you (or start a new one). Keep an eye on the Stack Exchange blog for more information as we move closer to the event - I'll post tips on what we learned from last year's event and some things to keep in mind when organizing your local meetup. See the [blog announcement](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/stack-overflow-meetup-everywhere-april-28-2012/) for some ideas about what your meetup can look like, why we're doing this, and some help navigating the meetup.com interface.

We'd love to see as many of you as possible participate in our Meetup Everywhere. We had over 2,000 people meet up around the world last year, and we've grown a lot since then. Help us spread the word by sharing info about this event through your blogs, social media accounts, lunches with coworkers, etc.

As always, if you have any questions or comments, do not hesitate to get in touch, and I hope to see you there!

Comment: Any users from Pittsburgh? I might go but don't want to be by myself! ^_^  V

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should Programmers.se hold a meet-and-greet?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2954/should-programmers-se-hold-a-meet-and-greet)

Comment: @JimG. Not a duplicate. This was posted by a CHAOS team member to advertise a Stack Exchange sponsored event for (from my understanding) the entire SE network. The previous question was in regards to a Programmers only meet-up.

Comment: @JimG. Not a duplicate. This is an announcement/invitation for an event that *is* happening - not asking whether there's any interest in such an event. (And as Thomas said, I'm an SE employee, and this is an official Stack Exchange event.) I just wanted to make sure that Programmers users knew they were invited even though it's called a "Stack Overflow" meetup; it's really for all sites in the SE network related to tech and/or programming.

Comment: @Laura: It's ironic (in a good way) that this is actually happening. When I proposed the idea, you wouldn't believe how many people downvoted the idea. Even Thomas Owens, who took my idea seriously, said it wasn't possible.

Comment: @JimG. I said it wasn't possible in a centralized manner, especially the context of Programmers (and even less possible in the context of the moderator elections). But with the entire SE network throwing their weight behind something, it's much easier to reach that critical mass of people. I'm really, really excited to be able to go, and I really hope that everyone goes to their local meetup.

Answer (score 3):

I'm planning on attending the [Cambridge, MA meetup](http://www.meetup.com/stackoverflow/Cambridge-MA/), assuming nothing else comes up. If anyone from Programmers will be there, be sure to let me know - I'd love to say hi. I'm hoping that people from southern New Hampshire and eastern Massachusetts, if not all the way from Connecticut and Rhode Island, will be there.

Comment: I'm curious about upvotes in this context. Are people excited that I'm going to the Cambridge meetup? Or attending my local meetup? Or are these people also in the greater Boston area who are attending and voicing their desire to go to this event?

Comment: Oh, I'm sure the upvotes are from people excited to get the chance to yell at your face for closing their questions ;P

Answer (score 3):

I'll be at the [Washington DC meetup](http://www.meetup.com/stackoverflow/DHS-MD/653302/) and hope to see folks from Programmers!